# Best practices for stringifying JSON inner objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stringify

Basically I have something like this:

**MyClass**

```
var MyClass = function() {
  this.num = 123;
  this.obj = new MyInnerClass();
};

MyClass.prototype.stringify = function() {
  return JSON.stringify(this);
};
```

**MyInnerClass**

```
var MyInnerClass = function() {
  this.foo = 456;
  this.bar = 'bonjour!';
};

MyInnerClass.prototype.stringify = function() {
  return JSON.stringify(this, function(k, v) {
    // ignores 'foo' attribute
    return k !== 'foo' ? v : undefined;
  });
};
```

Each class has its own `stringify` implementation, so when I do:

```
var mc = new MyClass();
mc.stringify();
```

I would like something like calling `MyClass.stringify` should stringify my `mc` object, but respecting inner objects `stringify` implementations. Once we don't have control over the `JSON.stringify` method logic, is there a *good* way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look on MDN at [**JSON.stringify**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior), you'll see a section that talks about a *toJSON* property

> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value is a function, then the toJSON() method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the toJSON() method when called will be serialized.

Basically, define a *toJSON* method for your *Object*  which creates another *Object*, but one that can be serialised as you desire. Then `JSON.stringify` will serialise the return of your `toJSON` function instead, i.e.

```
var MyClass = function() {
  this.num = 123;
  this.obj = new MyInnerClass();
};

var MyInnerClass = function() {
  this.foo = 456;
  this.bar = 'bonjour!';
};

MyInnerClass.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    // shallow clone `this`, except .foo
    var o = Object.create(null), k, blacklist = ['foo'];
    for (k in this) // loop over enumerable properties
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, k)) // ignore inherited properties
            if (blacklist.indexOf(k) === -1) // ignore blacklisted properties
                o[k] = this[k]; // add to our clone
    return o;
};

JSON.stringify(new MyClass()); // '{"num":123,"obj":{"bar":"bonjour!"}}'
```

This will also replace your need for the current *stringify* method.

---

Sadly you can't call `JSON.stringify(this)` inside `.toJSON` because it becomes circular and you get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, but you'd not get the desired result this way anyway as it would be serialised a second time, giving you a *String* in your *JSON*.

Comment: Yes, I saw that page about `toJSON`. So that's the only way.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that it won't work if I have a third inner object inside `MyInnerClass` that also implements a `stringify` method. But I think I can deal with it by making some adjusts to this function. Thanks anyway, Paul.